# heroku cannot find my cloudinary environment variables

Tags: reactjs, variables, heroku, environment-variables, cloudinary

I have a student who has an app that will host a photo to cloudinary then store it in his database. Everything worked fine locally but when he tried to host his app on heroku his app couldn't find his cloudinary environment variables. As far as I know he has done everything right and his app can find his other variables just not the cloudinary ones.  Has anyone run into a problem similar to this and can give me any direction?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import request from 'superagent';
const CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET = process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET
const CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL = process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL
export default class UpdateBook extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            id: "",
            title: "",
            blog_status: "",
            content: "", 
            featured_image_url: "", 
            formHidden: true,
            uploadedFile:'',
            uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: '',
            editMode: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.editBlog = this.editBlog.bind(this)
        this.handleContentChange = this.handleContentChange.bind(this)
        this.handleImageDrop = this.handleImageDrop.bind(this)
        this.componentConfig=this.componentConfig.bind(this);
        this.djsConfig=this.djsConfig.bind(this);
        this.deleteImage = this.deleteImage.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event){
      this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      })
  }
  handleContentChange(value) {
    this.setState({ content: value })
    }
    handleSubmit(event){
      let id = this.state.id
      let title = this.state.title;
      let blog_status = this.state.blog_status;
      let content = this.state.content;
      let featured_image_url = this.state.featured_image_url;
        fetch(`https://rwtw-backend-tw.herokuapp.com/update_blog/${id}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({title: title, blog_status: blog_status, content: content, featured_image_url: featured_image_url})
        }).then(response =>{
          response.json()
        }).then(responseData =>{
          return responseData
        }).catch(error => console.log("Fetch error", error))
    }
    handleImageDrop(files){
        this.setState({
            uploadedFile: files[0]
        })
        const currentFile = files[0]
        const myFileItemReader = new FileReader()
        myFileItemReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            this.setState({
                image_src: myFileItemReader.result
            })
        }, false)
        myFileItemReader.readAsDataURL(currentFile)
        let upload = request.post(CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL)
                .field("upload_preset", CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET)
                .field("file", this.state.uploadedFile);
            upload.end((err, response) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                } if (response.body.secure_url !== ""){
                    this.setState({
                        featured_image_url: response.body.secure_url
                    })
                }
            })
    }
    editBlog(){
      this.setState({editMode: true})
      this.setState({id: this.props.ourProp[0]})
      this.setState({title: this.props.ourProp[1]})
      this.setState({blog_status: this.props.ourProp[2]})
      this.setState({content: this.props.ourProp[3]})
      this.setState({featured_image_url: this.props.ourProp[4]})
  }
    componentConfig(){
        return{
            iconFileTypes: [".jpg", ".png"],
            showFiletypeIcon: true,
            postUrl: 'https://httpbin.org/post'
        }
    }
    djsConfig(){
        return{
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            maxFiles: 1
        }
    }
    deleteImage(){
        this.setState({
            featured_image_url: ""
        })
    }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.editMode ? 
            <form>
                    <div className="blog-manager-title">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            placeholder="Blog Title"
                            value = {this.state.title}
                            onChange = {this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="blog-manager-blog_status">
                        <select
                            type="text"
                            name="blog_status"
                            value = {this.state.blog_status}
                            onChange = {this.handleChange}
                        >
                            <option value="draft">Draft</option>
                            <option value="published">Published</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="blog-manager-content">
                        <ReactQuill
                            value={this.state.content}
                            onChange={this.handleContentChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    {this.state.featured_image_url !== "" ? 
                        <div>
                            <img src={this.state.featured_image_url}  style={{width: '400px'}}/>
                            <div className="image-removal-link">
                                <a onClick={() => this.deleteImage()}>Remove Image</a>
                            </div>
                        </div > :
                        <Dropzone 
                        onDrop={this.handleImageDrop}
                        multiple= {false}
                        accept="image/*"
                    >
                        Add a picture
                    </Dropzone>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="submit">
                        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}  value="submit">Add Blog</button>
                    </div>
                </form> : null}
                <button onClick={this.editBlog}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="edit"/></button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], we can't debug from a vague description.

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Comment: sorry about that, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In Heroku, there is a Cloudinary add-on. This will create a new Cloudinary account. So if your student create Cloudinary account outside Heroku, this will be 2 different account.
To double check this, from their Heroku account, try to login to Cloudinary, check if it's using the same cloud name.